# Subtraction of one string values from another string values

Tags: python

I got two strings, called `string1` and `string2`. Both consists of 6 different numbers.

What i would like to do in Python is to substract the values in string1 from the values in string2. How do I do this? I Guess this involves a for loop, since I only want to substract the first value in `string1` from the first value in `string2`. And substract the second value from `string1` from the second value in `string2` etc.

So if string 1 got the numbers

```
2 5 8 9 6 3
```

and string 2 got the numbers

```
2 3 5 9 3 2
```

I want to take "string1" minus "string2" to get

```
0 2 3 0 3 1
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: are your strings actually like `'2 5 8 9 6 3'` or `'258963'`? Because that changes the game quite a lot..

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this with `split()`, `zip()`, and `join()`:

```
" ".join([str(int(a) - int(b)) for a, b in zip(s1.split(), s2.split())])
```

Answer (score 3):

Building on @pault answer, you can have the following variation (removed the calls to `split()`, added a conditional):

```
"".join([str(int(a) - int(b)) if a != ' ' else ' ' for a, b in zip(s1, s2)])
```

which is simply fancier way of doing:

```
" ".join([str(int(a) - int(b)) for a, b in zip(s1.replace(' ', ''), s2.replace(' ', ''))])
```

The latter might be more readable.

Comment: I think of all the answers here, this is my favorite.  My only complaint would be that it sacrifices a bit of readability in favor of succinctness.  Quite clever, though.

Comment: @RagingRoosevelt That's true. Maybe it becomes more clear now.

Comment: @RagingRoosevelt : this answer assumes either equal length numbers (first variation) or single digit numbers (fancier way).

Comment: @Faibbus It also assumes that the question being answered is the one asked and not all possible variations of it.

Comment: @Faibbus, favorite != best

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re
s1 = '2 5 8 9 6 3'
s2 = '2 3 5 9 3 2'
new_string = ' '.join(str(a-b) for a, b in zip(map(int, re.findall('\d+', s1)), map(int, re.findall('\d+', s2))))
```

Output:

```
'0 2 3 0 3 1'
```

Comment: One of my favorite profs had a saying: "Don't kill flies with cannonballs".

Answer (score 1):

```
s1 = '2 5 8 9 6 3'
s2 = '2 3 5 9 3 2'
l1 = [int(x) for x in s1.split()]
l2 = [int(x) for x in s2.split()]
r1 = [v1 - v2 for v1, v2 in zip(l1, l2)]
```

`.split()` splits your string into a list based on where whitespace occurs (although you could provide it an argument to tell it to split on something else).

`[int(x) for x in s1.split()]` is a list comprehension.  It's a one-line loop that does stuff for each value in a list (the split string).  We need to convert the values in the split string into ints.

`zip(l1, l2)` takes the values in two lists and pairs them up.  You'd need the lists to have the same number of elements for this to work (we do).  From here, we use another list comprehension to pull out pairs of values and then take the difference.

edit (ty danihp): if you need the results to be a string, you can join the values in the list with `' '.join([str(x) for x in r1])` (this uses a space to separate elements in the list).

Answer (score 1):

Step for step:

```
s1 = '2 5 8 9 6 3'
s2 = '2 3 5 9 3 2'

s3 = [int(x) for x in s1.split()] # split and convert to int
s4 = [int(x) for x in s2.split()] # split and convert to int

s5 = [] # result
for idx in range(0,len(s3)): # length are equal so this is ok
       s5.append(s3[idx]-s4[idx]) # put into result

rv = " ".join([str(x) for x in s5]) # join result to string

print(s1)
print(s2)
print(s3)
print(s4)
print(s5)
print(rv)
```

Output:

```
2 5 8 9 6 3
2 3 5 9 3 2
[2, 5, 8, 9, 6, 3]
[2, 3, 5, 9, 3, 2]
[0, 2, 3, 0, 3, 1]
0 2 3 0 3 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since python is typed, you cannot subtact the strings: you have to convert each string to a list of integers and then subtract each one of the elements.

You can do this with only one loop:

```
s1 = '2 5 8 9 6 3'
s2 = '2 3 5 9 3 2'

list_diff = [int(x2) - int(x1) for x1, x2 in zip(s1.split(), s2.split())]

# or if you want the result as a string:
list_diff = [str(int(x1) - int(x2)) for x1, x2 in zip(s1.split(), s2.split())]
result = " ".join(list_diff)
```

Comment: Way to steal @pault's thunder.  And with a solution that gives an error (`TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found`)

Comment: You have to cast the elements of `list_diff` to `str` for `join()`.